# How to calculate uptime from table data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have table data for UP and DOWN counts and I want to calculate and display "uptime" as a percentage, for several targets within a the same table. Source counts have commas that must be removed, and I need to show the results to 3 decimal places (no rounding). Some targets begin with a number. The table itself is from an external source, displayed in an iFrame.

So far I have got the decimal places truncating, but I am looking for help parsing the table columns and rows to remove the commas and do the math.

> *(100 - (downCount / upCount * 100))*

EDIT: The accepted answer changed this to:

> *(upCount / (upCount + downCount) * 100)*

https://jsfiddle.net/ncarlton/d12ec7q3/1/

Vanilla JavaSript only please (no jQuery).

**JavaScript Starter:**

```
// these are the "correct" answers I'm trying to calculate from sourceTable data
let firstTargetCalc = (100 - (42 / 2218563 * 100));
let _2ndTargetCalc = (100 - (3 / 239384 * 100));
let thirdTargetCalc = (100 - (0 / 8340 * 100));

// this is how I want to truncate the decimals -- not rounding
function truncateDecimals(num, digits) {
  var numS = num.toString(),
    decPos = numS.indexOf('.'),
    substrLength = decPos == -1 ? numS.length : 1 + decPos + digits,
    trimmedResult = numS.substr(0, substrLength),
    finalResult = isNaN(trimmedResult) ? 0 : trimmedResult;

  return parseFloat(finalResult);
}

// here's the "final" answers with the truncation
let trunc1st = truncateDecimals(firstTargetCalc, 4)
let trunc2nd = truncateDecimals(_2ndTargetCalc, 4)
let trunc3rd = truncateDecimals(thirdTargetCalc, 4)

// here's what I want to display to the end user as the calculated uptime for each target
// alert('firsttarget uptime: ' + trunc1st + '%\n2ndtarget uptime: ' + trunc2nd + '%\nthirdtarget uptime: ' + trunc3rd + '%');
```

The full HTML with a large extraneous `<thead>` is in the JSFiddle. But the important part might look like this in the `<tbody>` for three targets. The number of targets will vary but will usually be fewer than ten.

**HTML:**

````
        <tr>
          <td class="cell-hover ng-scope" ng-click="clickHandler($event)">firsttarget</td>
          <td>UP</td>
          <td class="numeric-value">2,218,563</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell-hover ng-scope" ng-click="clickHandler($event)">firsttarget</td>
          <td>DOWN</td>
          <td class="numeric-value">42</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell-hover ng-scope" ng-click="clickHandler($event)">2ndtarget</td>
          <td>UP</td>
          <td class="numeric-value">239,384</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell-hover ng-scope" ng-click="clickHandler($event)">2ndtarget</td>
          <td>DOWN</td>
          <td class="numeric-value">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell-hover ng-scope" ng-click="clickHandler($event)">thirdtarget</td>
          <td>UP</td>
          <td class="numeric-value">8,340</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell-hover ng-scope" ng-click="clickHandler($event)">thirdtarget</td>
          <td>DOWN</td>
          <td class="numeric-value">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNDdW.png
````

Comment: Unfrotunately it ain't clear what you're asking - what exactly do you need help with? Getting rid of the commas in e.g. 2,218,563?

Comment: thank you for letting me know, and sorry! I am still learning how to keep my questions concise here. fortunately for me @Pavlos Karalis managed to solve everything, even something I didn't realize needed correcting!

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it sorted! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to parse your table rather than iterating rows; your calculation to get the percentage is also incorrect. See snippet for working example.

```
function showTableData() {
  const targetTable = document.getElementById('jstable'); // where to draw the new table
  const sourceTable = document.querySelector(".table"); // set kibana as 

  const innerText = sourceTable.innerText;
  const ups = innerText.match(/(\w*(target))\s*(UP)\s*[\d,]*\d(?! )/g);
  const downs = innerText.match(/(\w*(target))\s*(DOWN)\s*[\d,]*\d(?! )/g);

  let innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < ups.length; i++) {
    const up = ups[i];
    const down = downs[i];
    const target = up.match(/(\w*(target))/)[0];
    const upCount = parseInt(up.match(/[\d,]*\d$/)[0].replace(/,/g, ""));
    const downCount = parseInt(down.match(/[\d,]*\d$/)[0].replace(/,/g, ""));
    const percentage = (upCount / (upCount + downCount) * 100).toFixed(3)
    innerHTML += `${target} uptime: ${percentage}%<br/><br/>`
  }
  targetTable.innerHTML = innerHTML;
}
```

```js
// these are the "correct" answers I'm trying to calculate from sourceTable data
let firstTargetCalc = (100 - (42 / 2218563 * 100));
let _2ndTargetCalc = (100 - (3 / 239384 * 100));
let thirdTargetCalc = (100 - (0 / 8340 * 100));

// this is how I want to truncate the decimals -- not rounding
function truncateDecimals(num, digits) {
  var numS = num.toString(),
    decPos = numS.indexOf('.'),
    substrLength = decPos == -1 ? numS.length : 1 + decPos + digits,
    trimmedResult = numS.substr(0, substrLength),
    finalResult = isNaN(trimmedResult) ? 0 : trimmedResult;

  return parseFloat(finalResult);
}

// here's the "final" answers with the truncation
let trunc1st = truncateDecimals(firstTargetCalc, 4)
let trunc2nd = truncateDecimals(_2ndTargetCalc, 4)
let trunc3rd = truncateDecimals(thirdTargetCalc, 4)

// here's what I want to display to the end user as the calculated uptime for each target
// alert('firsttarget uptime: ' + trunc1st + '%\n2ndtarget uptime: ' + trunc2nd + '%\nthirdtarget uptime: ' + trunc3rd + '%');


// this will eventually be run within the function to set the iFrame URL
// need to wait for the iFrame to load to get data for calculations
// for now we will present a button...

function showTableData() {
  const targetTable = document.getElementById('jstable'); // where to draw the new table
  const sourceTable = document.querySelector(".table"); // set kibana as 

  const innerText = sourceTable.innerText;
  const ups = innerText.match(/(\w*(target))\s*(UP)\s*[\d,]*\d(?! )/g);
  const downs = innerText.match(/(\w*(target))\s*(DOWN)\s*[\d,]*\d(?! )/g);

  let innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < ups.length; i++) {
    const up = ups[i];
    const down = downs[i];
    const target = up.match(/(\w*(target))/)[0];
    const upCount = parseInt(up.match(/[\d,]*\d$/)[0].replace(/,/g, ""));
    const downCount = parseInt(down.match(/[\d,]*\d$/)[0].replace(/,/g, ""));
    const percentage = (upCount / (upCount + downCount) * 100).toFixed(3)
    innerHTML += `${target} uptime: ${percentage}%<br/><br/>`
  }
  targetTable.innerHTML = innerHTML;
}


/*

function showTableData() {
  document.getElementById('jstable').innerHTML = ""; // where to draw the new table
  let sourceTable = document.querySelector(".table"); // set "source" table

  for (var i = 0, row; row = sourceTable.rows[i]; i++) {
    //iterate through rows
    //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
      //iterate through columns
      //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
    }
  }
}



  /*calc.prototype.toFixedDown = function(digits) {
      var re = new RegExp("(\\d+\\.\\d{" + digits + "})(\\d)"),
          m = this.toString().match(re);
      return m ? parseFloat(m[1]) : this.valueOf();
  };*/


/*
// rounding function
function roundTo(n, digits) {
    var negative = false;
    if (digits === undefined) {
        digits = 0;
    }
        if( n < 0) {
        negative = true;
      n = n * -1;
    }
    var multiplicator = Math.pow(10, digits);
    n = parseFloat((n * multiplicator).toFixed(11));
    n = (Math.round(n) / multiplicator).toFixed(2);
    if( negative ) {    
        n = (n * -1).toFixed(2);
    }
    return n;
}

// set the vars 
/*let uptimeCells = document.querySelectorAll("td");
    for (let i = 0; i < uptimeCells.length; i+=3) {
      let uptimeTarget = uptimeCells[i].firstChild.data;
      let uptimeFilter = uptimeCells[i + 1].firstChild.data;
      let uptimeCount = uptimeCells[i + 2].firstChild.data;
              console.log(uptimeTarget, uptimeFilter, uptimeCount);
    }
//      if () {
//      }
return `<p>${this.targetName} ${this.calculatedUptime}</p>`;*/
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="rebuild-table">
    <p><input type="button" id="bt" value="Show Rebuilt Table" onclick="showTableData()" /></p>
    <p id="jstable"></p>
    <h1>
      Expected Results
    </h1>
    <div id=results>
      <p>
        firsttarget uptime: 99.998%
        <!--(100-((42/2218563)*100))-->
      </p>
      <p>
        2ndtarget uptime: 99.999%
        <!--(100-((3/239384)*100)) rounded up from 99.9987..-->
      </p>
      <p>
        thirdtarget uptime: 100.000%
        <!--(100-((0/8340)*100))-->
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>
      Data
    </h1>
    <!--THE TABLE BELOW IS PRESENTED WITHIN AN IFRAME BUT FOR THE JSFIDDLEWE WILL COMMENT OUT THE IFRAME ELEMENT
    <iframe id="iframeURL">-->
    <table class="table table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <!-- ngRepeat: col in ::columns -->
          <th ng-repeat="col in ::columns" ng-click="paginatedTable.sortColumn($index)" class="">
            <span ng-bind="::col.title" class="ng-binding">targets</span>
            <!-- ngIf: col.info -->
            <!-- ngIf: col.sortable !== false --><i ng-if="col.sortable !== false" class="fa ng-scope fa-sort" ng-class="{
                'fa-sort-asc': paginatedTable.sort.columnIndex === $index &amp;&amp; paginatedTable.sort.direction === 'asc',
                'fa-sort-desc': paginatedTable.sort.columnIndex === $index &amp;&amp; paginatedTable.sort.direction === 'desc',
                'fa-sort': paginatedTable.sort.columnIndex !== $index || paginatedTable.sort.direction === null
              }">
            </i>
            <!-- end ngIf: col.sortable !== false -->
            <!-- ngIf: col.filterable --><i aria-label="Click on a cell to filter" ng-if="col.filterable" class="fa fa-search ng-scope" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" tooltip="Click on a cell to filter"></i>
            <!-- end ngIf: col.filterable -->
          </th>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: col in ::columns -->
          <th ng-repeat="col in ::columns" ng-click="paginatedTable.sortColumn($index)" class="">
            <span ng-bind="::col.title" class="ng-binding">filters</span>
            <!-- ngIf: col.info -->
            <!-- ngIf: col.sortable !== false --><i ng-if="col.sortable !== false" class="fa ng-scope fa-sort" ng-class="{
                'fa-sort-asc': paginatedTable.sort.columnIndex === $index &amp;&amp; paginatedTable.sort.direction === 'asc',
                'fa-sort-desc': paginatedTable.sort.columnIndex === $index &amp;&amp; paginatedTable.sort.direction === 'desc',
                'fa-sort': paginatedTable.sort.columnIndex !== $index || paginatedTable.sort.direction === null
              }">
            </i>
            <!-- end ngIf: col.sortable !== false -->
            <!-- ngIf: col.filterable -->
          </th>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: col in ::columns -->
          <th ng-repeat="col in ::columns" ng-click="paginatedTable.sortColumn($index)" class="visualize-table-right">
            <span ng-bind="::col.title" class="ng-binding">Count</span>
            <!-- ngIf: col.info -->
            <!-- ngIf: col.sortable !== false --><i ng-if="col.sortable !== false" class="fa ng-scope fa-sort" ng-class="{
                'fa-sort-asc': paginatedTable.sort.columnIndex === $index &amp;&amp; paginatedTable.sort.direction === 'asc',
                'fa-sort-desc': paginatedTable.sort.columnIndex === $index &amp;&amp; paginatedTable.sort.direction === 'desc',
                'fa-sort': paginatedTable.sort.columnIndex !== $index || paginatedTable.sort.direction === null
              }">
            </i>
            <!-- end ngIf: col.sortable !== false -->
            <!-- ngIf: col.filterable -->
          </th>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: col in ::columns -->
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody kbn-rows="page" kbn-rows-min="perPage">
        <tr>
          <td class="cell-hover ng-scope" ng-click="clickHandler($event)">firsttarget</td>
          <td>UP</td>
          <td class="numeric-value">2,218,563</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell-hover ng-scope" ng-click="clickHandler($event)">firsttarget</td>
          <td>DOWN</td>
          <td class="numeric-value">42</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell-hover ng-scope" ng-click="clickHandler($event)">2ndtarget</td>
          <td>UP</td>
          <td class="numeric-value">239,384</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell-hover ng-scope" ng-click="clickHandler($event)">2ndtarget</td>
          <td>DOWN</td>
          <td class="numeric-value">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell-hover ng-scope" ng-click="clickHandler($event)">thirdtarget</td>
          <td>UP</td>
          <td class="numeric-value">8,340</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell-hover ng-scope" ng-click="clickHandler($event)">thirdtarget</td>
          <td>DOWN</td>
          <td class="numeric-value">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!--</iframe>-->
  <p>
    Notes: some targets begin with numbers. The final implementation will have various numbers of targets to calculate. Cannot change the table itself, other than the names of the UP and DOWN filters (e.g., cannot add id="" to any table elements because it's
    generated externally). The entire 'thead' element is not important to this project.</p>
</body>
```